# TFS doesn't show the solution

Tags: tfs

I have a problem with TFS 
when I connect to a team project and configure workspace and click on Map & Get button, it shows "successfully mapped" message but there is no solution in Solutions panel, there is just a text "there were no solution found"

And when I try to get latest version or get specific version in source control explorer,it shows a message that says "all files are up to date, no file were updated because the requested file versions were previously downloaded" but there is no solution and project in mapped folder

I don't have this problem with other team projects

Does somebody know what's the reason?and what can I do to solve it?

**Thanks**

**Edit**

when I click on *"map & get"* for the first time,as usual a dialog box with title *"calculating items to download"* appears and then another dialog box with title *"get"*, but in the second dialog box the green progress bar doesn't fill and then the message *"workspace successfully mapped"* appears in team explorer home and as I said before, there is no solution

Comment: In source control explorer under "server-name/DefaultCollection" node there is nothing but in the team explorer there is a child node with the name of the project that I wanted to get

Comment: Why there is nothing? Even though you didn't map your project, you can still see the solution and files under the project with gray icon. Could you provide the screenshot of Soulution Explorer and Team Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To narrow down your issue, you can try below methods:

1. Make sure your local mapping folder is on a hard disk with enough
   space.
2. Try to Removing the mapping of the project(Right Click your
   project→Advanced→Remove mapping) and remap to another folder.
3. Clear [TFS cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx) and VS cache

According to your above message

> In source control explorer under "server-name/DefaultCollection" node
>   there is nothing

I was wondering whether there is a solution with the project in TFS.

- Try to map the project on another computer with another account.
- Try to make sure you have enough **permissions to get the project**.
- Check whether you select the right project collection which including
  the project.
- Check whether your solution and files are in the excluded list of
  pending changes.

Comment: thanks a lot ...,you're right. It was related to permission

Answer (score 0):

Probably you deleted the files after you did a Get Latest Version operation.

Try to use the Get Specific Version then check the "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version".

Comment: hello I tried the get specific version with that option but it didn't work

Comment: also there is no file or solution in mapped folder

Comment: Can you post here what do you get in the Output window - Show output from: Source Control - Team Foundation when do Get Specific Version?

Comment: there is nothing in output window. It's empty because get operation ends up with an error. I wrote the error message before "all files are up to date..."

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the problem. It was related to my access level in team project.

I was the 7th member of the team and because in this free version a team can only have 5 basic and advanced members, automatically my access level was changed to stackholder and as you know a stackholder access level has some limitations.